# python regex to find name of fielder

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website and parse cricket scoreboard using scrapy. I have been able to do most of it except for the field who caught the ball. There can be several ways in which the text can be found such as

1. **c Soumya Sarkar b Rubel Hossain**
2. **c Imrul Kayes b Mosaddek Hossain**
3. **c & b Sodhi**
4. **c Anderson b Boult**
5. **c †Lenton b Cummins**

The ideas is to get the fielder name who has taken the catch which means

- Soumya Sarkar
- Imrul Kayes
- Sodhi
- Anderson

I have come up with following regex so far

```
(c\s)([A-Za-z]*)
(c & b)(\s[a-zA-Z]*)
```

These work when the I have just last names in the catcher such as Anderson, sodhi but they don't work with full names. I need to capture the complete name in a single group that I can use in latter stages.

I know these might not be perfect so any suggestion on existing ones are also welcome

**Edit**
Added a special case in which name is preceded by dagger symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for:

```
c(?: & b)? (.+?)(?: b |$)
```

You have two cases for the start:

`c` or `c & b`

And then you want to match as many characters as possible until you find `b` or the end of your line

Here is what I get using python2.7:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('c(?: & b)? (.+?)(?: b |$)')

NAMES = ('c Soumya Sarkar b Rubel Hossain',
         'c Imrul Kayes b Mosaddek Hossain',
         'c & b Sodhi',
         'c Anderson b Boult',
         'c †Lenton b Cummins ')

for name in NAMES:
    w = pattern.match(name)
    print w.group(1)
```

Output:

```
Soumya Sarkar
Imrul Kayes
Sodhi
Anderson
†Lenton
```

Comment: but it does return the bowler name also which comes after "b". Also it doesn't select anything in c & b case. Also can you add a bit of explaination

Comment: I was trying it on regex101 I will try in my code and then update

Comment: I corrected the regex in my first edit (about the time when you posted your comment) : you can retry on regex101, it should work.

Comment: Thanks it works but I have another exceptional scenario where the text could be c †Lenton b Cummins (name preceded by dagger symbol) is it possible to accommodate this in the expression?

Answer (score 2):

You could go for:

```
(?|                     # a so called "branch reset", only supported by the regex module
    c\                  # a "c "
    (?P<catcher>.{2,}?) # at least two characters, lazily -> group "catcher"
    \ b\                # followed by " b "
|                       # or
    c\ & \ b\           # "c & b "
    (?P<catcher>.+)     # capture the rest of the string -> group "catcher"
)
```

---

In `Python` code:

```
# the newer regex module
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'''
  (?|
  c\ 
  (?P<catcher>.{2,}?)
  \ b\ 
  |
  c\ & \ b\ 
  (?P<catcher>.+))
''', re.VERBOSE)

sampletext = """
c Soumya Sarkar b Rubel Hossain
c Imrul Kayes b Mosaddek Hossain
c & b Sodhi
c Anderson b Boult
"""

catchers = [m.group('catcher') for m in rx.finditer(sampletext)]
print(catchers)
# ['Soumya Sarkar', 'Imrul Kayes', 'Sodhi', 'Anderson']
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/koe73z/2).
You need to have the newer `regex` module (`pip install regex`) to make this work.